# ldconfig doesn't recognise new library in directory

Tags: ubuntu, linker, shared-libraries, ld

I am trying to compile a package that needs libpthread**s**.so. My system (Ubuntu 20.04) has libpthread.so (no 's' at the end of thread).

I tried linking libpthread**s**.so to libpthread.so but ldconfig doesn't recognise the new file. I did this:

```
> cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> ln -s libpthread-2.31.so libpthreads.so
> rm  /etc/ld.so.cache
> ldconfig
```

I ran "ldconfig" a couple of times, then checked to see if it was finding the new library:

```
> ldconfig -p | grep libpthrea
        libpthread.so.0 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libpthread.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
```

Why is ldconfig not finding the new library (it is only finding the original libpthread.so, not libpthread**s**.so)?

I also tried making a copy (instead of a sym link), but that didn't help.

The directory where the file is located (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu) is known to the linker:

```
> ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")              <---- this directory
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried linking libpthreads.so to libpthread.so but ldconfig doesn't recognise the new file.

You *don't need* `ldconfig` to recognize this library. You just need the linker to recognize it (which it will) to link against it.

Once you link your program (if you succeed), the binary will record that it needs `libpthread.so.0` (because that's the `SONAME` of `libpthread.so`), and `ldconfig` *does* know how to find that.

P.S. You will likely fail to actually build your program without modifications -- `pthreads` probably corresponds to the really old POSIX threads standard, so function prototypes will not match.
And if you need to modify the program, you might as well change its link line to use `-lpthread` (without the `s`).